# Malformed input-Template format error: Every Default member must be a string (Cloudformation template problems)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to validate a cloudformation template, and cfn-validate returns a useless error of

> "Malformed input-Template format error: Every Default member must be a string".

Does anybody have an idea on how to debug this? It would be awesome if `cfn-
validate` would return errors or at least resource names when errors are given.

CloudformationTemplates are incredibly painful to debug.

Comment: The error message seems pretty useful to me. Go through every default member and validate that they're all strings, maybe?

Comment: Error strings should be on a seperate line and put in as a quote using the > 

use the `backtick to highlight code inline of a sentence

Comment: Keep in mind that the results of `Fn::Join` do NOT count as strings

Answer (score 30):

This problem occurs when you specify `Parameter`s and have their default value calculated in some way (usually be referencing other parameters).

This definition is not valid - parameters' default values must be strictly strings that the command line tool can replace with other strings.

Comment: yeah , even i faced this error .Just check this value should be STRICT STRING " "Default": "aaa-bbb-ccc".No other value will be accepted here .Earlier i was passing array of Strings , so got this error.

Comment: Do you have a reference to AWS documentation for that? @guss

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg - the documentation for this is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html . It's not immediately obvious from the docs, but when they say "A value of the appropriate type" they mean an actual value and not a formula or code to compute a value. Its not true that has it be a strict string - although all JSON examples are strings, even those that are for a Number type - they can also be YAML numbers, but they do have to be literal values.

Answer (score 20):

I received the same error message when using the Parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList` in my cfn template.

```
  LoadBalancerSubnets:
    Description: List of subnets for the ApplicationLoadBalancer
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: [ "subnet-123456", "subnet-012345" ]
```

This was due to my mis-interpretation of the `CommaDelimitedList` type. I thought it is actually a list but it turns out that the value should be a single String value in which the various elements should be separated by a comma. 
So, I changed my template to look like this:

```
  LoadBalancerSubnets:
    Description: List of subnets for the ApplicationLoadBalancer
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: "subnet-123456,subnet-012345"
```

and this worked.

The error was a very generic one and there may be other scenarios as well in which the same error gets thrown.

However, I thought about sharing my experience with this error so it may help others who got stuck with the same problem.

Comment: "The error was a very generic one" -- indeed. This fixed my issue where `Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` and the default needed to be `subnet-123,subnet-456`

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this error for the `Outputs` description field as well (I was using `!Sub`). Had to remove `!Sub` and just use plain text.

Comment: Ditto for the `Description` inside a Parameter list.  Was hoping to `!Sub` in the ${AWS::Region}, but no, that would have been too useful.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in Cloudformation Outputs definition when the result of a ´Fn::...´ is a list and not a string.

To make strings out of Lists you can ´Fn::Join´ the list result to a comma separated string. e.g.:

```
 "VpcSubnets": {
      "Export": {
        "Name": "VpcSubnets"
      },
      "Value": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          ",",
          {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "MyVpc",
              "Subnets"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have unnecessary !Ref or !Sub like this one

```
Parameters:
  RelationTableName: 
    Description: relations table name
    Type: String
    Default: !Ref "relations"
```